# Creating NOR/NAND gate with a loop

Tags: c, arrays, lis

I want to implement a boolean NAND/NOR gate. Problem is I no of inputs to the gate I learn on the fly in the code itself i.e I dont know in advance how many inputs it may have. Following is the code for OR. But I cant figure out a way to do it for NOR/NAND. What should be initial value for result? Is there a way around?

```
result=0; //non controlling value for OR
for(i = 0; i < fin; i++)
{
value=unodes[i];
result=(result | value);
}
final_value = result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing AND/OR first (by taking the initial value as 1/0) and then taking its compliment?

Comment: Thanks. Stupid question. Realized it as soon as I posted it.